# Where to SaveState on App Suspension

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, savestate, suspend

*(Note:  The following refers to a Hub App for Windows Phone 8.1)*

When the Windows Phone suspends, all unsaved data is lost.  Should the data be saved as it is added/changed? Or should it be saved on Suspension?  Or a mix of the two?

Specifically:

Important data that needs to be maintained forever, I can see no problem with saving it as it comes.  But if it just data needed for a few seconds, it seems like overkill to save it unless the app suspends.

It also seems cleaner to save everything at once in a single method, but that just may be my personal preference.

If the data should be saved on suspension, does it matter where in the following method it goes?  (this is called in the `OnSuspending()` method.)

```
    public static async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // Save the navigation state for all registered frames
            foreach (var weakFrameReference in _registeredFrames)
            {
                Frame frame;
                if (weakFrameReference.TryGetTarget(out frame))
                {
                    SaveFrameNavigationState(frame);
                }
            }

            // Serialize the session state synchronously to avoid asynchronous access to shared
            // state
            MemoryStream sessionData = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), _knownTypes);
            serializer.WriteObject(sessionData, _sessionState);

            // Get an output stream for the SessionState file and write the state asynchronously
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(sessionStateFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                sessionData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await sessionData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new SuspensionManagerException(e);
        }
    }
```

Also, a side question, restoring the data should just be front-loaded in the `NavigationHelper_LoadState()` method, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What to do with your data depends on few factors:

- how your data imoprtant is - if you have some crucial data, then save it right away,
- how big is your data - if your data is very big then it might be impossible to save it while the app is suspending - limited time,
- think if you are able to reproduce the data after resuming - if you have some data that are calculated within an app and you can reproduce the process after resuming, then there may be no need to save the data.

You can save if few places - Settings (*Local/Roaming*), LocalStorage (*file/database*), there is also cache.

Note that NavigationHelper contains a helper method which you can use to save/restore your data:

```
// in your Page
private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
{
    e.PageState.Add("yourKey", data);
}
```

It works like *Dictionary* which is serialized to a file *sessionStateFilename*.

You can also do it manually to a file - it will be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter where the save method goes?

- You can only trust 'Window.Current.Activated'

  ```
  AddHandler Window.Current.Activated, AddressOf WindowActivated

  Private Sub WindowActivated(sender As Object, e As Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs)
    If e.WindowActivationState = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated Then
      If TypeOf rootFrame.Content Is MyPage Then
          Dim MyPage1 = DirectCast(rootFrame.Content, MyPage)
          MyPage1.SaveAsync()
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
  ```

It seems cleaner to save everything at once in a single method.

- That is my personal preference aswell.

Should data be restored in the NavigationHelper_LoadState?

- I prefer App.OnLaunched